# django-staticfiles breaking the admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using the [django-staticfiles](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-staticfiles/0.1.2) app to serve css files, but this also prevents required admin css files (media/base.css, media/dashboard.css) from being loaded. It seems like I need to exclude the admin app, but adding it to the `STATICFILES_EXCLUDED_APPS` hasn't helped.

Here are the relevant bits from my settings.py file:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_EXCLUDED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'staticfiles',

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'll assume this is for development as you shouldn't serve static content with django-staticfiles.)

You have to define the `ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT` variable in your settings.py file and point it to the location of the admin css files. I've moved these files out of site-packages to be in a similar location as my other static files for ease of deployment.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. And yes it is just for development.